# Long commands in Java

Tags: java

I am learning to code in Java

I know what namespaces, classes and methods are
with that knowledge I understand code such as the following

```
CharSequence v = new BackwardString("whale");
v.toString();
```

However sometimes you see examples of code which are longer than this
an example being

```
dictionary.subSet("a","ab").size();
```

In the ubove example dictionary is a class and subSet() is a method.
However size() is also a method but methods cannot contain other methods, so where does size() come from and why does it work?

Another common example which i have used without giving any thought to until now is

```
System.out.printLn();
```

in this case would System be a namespace, out be a class and printLn() be a method?

Comment: System is a class, static classes are similar to a namespace. Java doesn't have namespaces though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dictionary.subSet("a","ab").size();`

It's a chaining of method calls. `dictionary.subSet("a","ab")` returns a `String` object, on which you call the `size` method.

`System.out.println()`

`System` is a class (`java.lang.System`), `out` is a static variable of that class whose type is `PrintStream`, and `println` is a method of `PrintStream`.

Answer (score 0):

In this example:

```
dictionary.subSet("a","ab").size();
```

method *subSet* returns an object with method *size* which gets invoked after *subSet* returns.

Similar thing happens with another snippet:

```
System.out.printLn();
```

Class *System* contains a static field *out* which has a method *println*

This is a common practice in Java programming to pipeline method calls. Sometimes an object can return itself allowing you can call multiple methods in one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary.subSet("a","ab").size();
```

The subSet method returns a String object, you are then calling .size() on this String. It is shorthand for doing the following

```
String a = dictionary.subSet("a","ab")
int size = a.size();

System.out.println()
```

System.out returns a PrintStream method, and you are invoking the println() method of that object.

Answer (score 0):

This is called `Method Chanining`

```
System.out.printLn();=
```

`System` is a class

`PrintStream` is a class again // ref is out

`println()` is a function

Answer (score 0):

The `.` selection is done as follows:

```
(dictionary.subSet("a","ab")).size();

Set s = dictionary.subSet("a","ab");
s.size();
```

The method subSet delivers (likely) a Set,
and Set has a method size.

This is called "chaining".

To get a feeling of it:

```
BigDecimal n = BigDecimal.valueOf("123456780.12");
n = n.multiply(n).add(n).divide(BigDecimal.TWO).subtract(n);
```

BigDecimal does large numbers with precise fixed point arithmetic.
It cannot use operators, and the above is a normal style.

Selectors (that might be chained:

- `.` member
- `[` index `]`
- `(` function arguments `)`